# Is it possible to fill down the entire column by Excel formula as in GUI? #gspread

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

Is it possible in **gspread** library to fill down  the entire column by Excel formula as in GUI, without going through each line?

Currently, I'm using the method below:

```
def _update_formula(sheet):
     for i in range(2, 100):
         sheet.update_acell(f'AL{i}', f'=if(B{i}=B{i+1},1,0)')
```

Is it possible, for example, to add 1 line and copy formula the rest of rows as in the GUI. Do you have any ideas how to optimize it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put a formula of `=if(B{i}=B{i+1},1,0)` to all cells in the specific column.
- You want to achieve this using gspread for python.

In your script, you use the formula of `'=if(B{i}=B{i+1},1,0'`. But in this case, it might be `'=if(B{i}=B{i+1},1,0)'`. In this case, how about the following modified script? In this modification, the formula is put using the RepeatCellRequest of batchUpdate method.

#### Modified script:

```py
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "###" # Please set your sheet name.

spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId) # or client.open("###Spreadsheet title###")
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
requests = {
    "repeatCell": {
        "cell": {
            "userEnteredValue": {
                "formulaValue": "=if(B1=B2,1,0)"
            }
        },
        "range": {
            "sheetId": sheet.id,
            "startColumnIndex": 2,
            "endColumnIndex": 3,
            "startRowIndex": 1
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredValue.formulaValue"
    }
}
res = spreadsheet.batch_update({"requests": [requests]})
```

- `"startColumnIndex": 2` and `"endColumnIndex": 3` of `range` means the column "C".
- `"startRowIndex": 1` of `range` and no `endRowIndex` means that the formula is put from the row 2 to end of row.
- About GridRange, you can see it at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange).

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batch_upddate#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)